# Using requests for a url that downloads a csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, web-scraping, python-requests

with the following link a csv file gets download. I am unable to use it as a pandas data frame

the header here has to be copy pasted from the red box of attached image as the website dont support the general request.

[this is the NSE website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MngI.png).

[this is the Dev Tools from where the headers has to be copied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sa4LX.png)

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import csv

header = ''''''



def header_in_dictionary(header):
    unwanted = '''sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="111", "Not(A:Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="111"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin'''
    
    header = header.replace(unwanted,'')
    
    header_list = header.split('\n')
    
    
    key_list = ['accept','accept-encoding','accept-language','cookie','referer','user-agent','x-requested-with']
    
    value_list = []
    
    for ele in header_list:
        if ':' in ele:
            value_list.append(ele[ele.index(':') + 2:len(ele)])
        else:
            None
    

    
    header_dictionary = {}
    index_counter = 0
    for ele in key_list :
        header_dictionary[ele] = value_list[index_counter]
        index_counter += 1
    
      
    return header_dictionary



aa = requests.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ASIANPAINT&series=[%22EQ%22]&from=01-04-2021&to=9-03-2023&csv=true", headers = header_in_dictionary(header))
```

I want to use the data of csv file. for that I have to convert it to pandas data frame.

Answer (score 2):

Use `requests.Session` because you need to store a cookie:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/111.0'}

# Create a HTTP session
session = requests.Session()

# Get cookies
response = session.get('https://www.nseindia.com/', headers=headers)

# Download csv
response = session.get("https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=ASIANPAINT&series=[%22EQ%22]&from=01-04-2021&to=9-03-2023&csv=true", headers=headers)

# Create dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(response.content))
```

Output:

```
>>> df
           Date  series      OPEN      HIGH       LOW  PREV. CLOSE       ltp     close      vwap     52W H     52W L   VOLUME             VALUE   No of trades 
0    09-Mar-2023      EQ  2,862.00  2,872.45  2,836.85     2,859.55  2,856.00  2,853.55  2,855.48  3,582.90  2,560.00   774224  2,210,782,913.25          51928
1    08-Mar-2023      EQ  2,870.00  2,870.00  2,827.00     2,864.55  2,857.00  2,859.55  2,850.88  3,582.90  2,560.00   580250  1,654,225,600.65          50105
2    06-Mar-2023      EQ  2,843.00  2,884.00  2,830.25     2,828.85  2,861.60  2,864.55  2,869.75  3,582.90  2,560.00  1050267  3,013,998,661.15          74159
3    03-Mar-2023      EQ  2,837.05  2,852.00  2,810.65     2,833.90  2,830.15  2,828.85  2,826.34  3,582.90  2,560.00   679295  1,919,921,555.35          64015
4    02-Mar-2023      EQ  2,831.00  2,849.00  2,811.00     2,840.90  2,833.00  2,833.90  2,832.79  3,582.90  2,560.00   604523  1,712,488,953.55          44537
..           ...     ...       ...       ...       ...          ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...      ...               ...            ...
477  08-Apr-2021      EQ  2,630.00  2,658.40  2,628.00     2,628.60  2,643.95  2,650.65  2,647.85  2,873.45  1,482.95   897483  2,376,398,265.70          60031
478  07-Apr-2021      EQ  2,605.00  2,668.05  2,600.10     2,611.60  2,621.60  2,628.60  2,644.44  2,873.45  1,482.95  1937977  5,124,871,995.00         110658
479  06-Apr-2021      EQ  2,526.00  2,620.00  2,504.50     2,510.65  2,610.10  2,611.60  2,585.83  2,873.45  1,482.95  3372846  8,721,612,490.50         178805
480  05-Apr-2021      EQ  2,558.00  2,558.00  2,484.50     2,551.75  2,512.00  2,510.65  2,509.91  2,873.45  1,482.95  1268939  3,184,919,119.35          74815
481  01-Apr-2021      EQ  2,532.00  2,564.55  2,532.00     2,537.40  2,545.00  2,551.75  2,549.80  2,873.45  1,482.95  1219588  3,109,711,122.00          54928

[482 rows x 14 columns]
```